# Protractor , get count by css is not working

Tags: css, protractor

In page there columns like this:

```
<span translate="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Number of Products</span>

<span translate="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Number of Processed Products</span>

number of preprocessed Products
number of Products
```

So, to check the page if it is present, i try to check those columns is active.

So, i do this:

```
        var el =  element.all(by.css( "Products</span>"));
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(el), 5000);
```

but error is

```
Message:
    Failed: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
  Stack:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
        at ProtractorExpectedConditions.presenceOf (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/expectedConditions.js:354:39)
```

so i change to this

```
                    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
                 //   browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(el), 1000);
                      browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.
cssContainingText('span', 'Products'))), 5000);  // maximum wait of 5 seconds

                    expect((element(by.cssContainingText('span', 'Products'))).count()).toEqual(1);
```

but error is

```
  Message:
    Failed: element(...).count is not a function
```

when i do this

```
 var el = element(by.cssContainingText('span', 'Products'));
                var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
                browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(el), 5000);  // maximum wait of 5 seconds
                expect(el.count()).toEqual(1);
```

eror is

```
 Message:
    Failed: element(...).count is not a function








  var el =  element.all(by.css( "Products"));
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(el), 1000);


        expect(el.count()).toEqual(1);
```

this error

```
 Failed: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
```

it is same for '' or ""

Comment: what do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: the error with `bind` is because those aren't valid locators.  When you pass `element(by.css("Products"))`, it is looking for a <Products> tag because thats what you specified.  Same with `element.all(by.css( "Products</span>"))`... thats not how you include a <span> tag in a locator.  You should review how CSS locators work

Answer (score 1):

Basically the locators which you were using are invalid and `count` method will work only with `element.all()` and `$$()` methods.Try the below code,

```
var el = element.all(by.cssContainingText('span', 'Products'));
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(el), 5000);  
expect(el.count()).toEqual(1);
```

Comment: @mark browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(el), 5000);   - here el is not a single element. more than one element. So try browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(el.first()), 5000);

Comment: try with this one:  **var el = element.all(by.tagName('span'));**

Comment: @Danny there are another span values different than i wrote in the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
                 //   browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(el), 1000);
                      browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.
cssContainingText('span', 'Products'))), 5000);  // maximum wait of 5 seconds

                    expect((element.all(by.cssContainingText('span', 'Products'))).count()).toEqual(1);
```

Comment: Check this link - https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count